# Using WMS with ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, wms

Is it possible to use a WMS with ggmap?

I have found a lot of tutorials for using WMS with the leaflet package, but I would rather plot my map with ggmap as I dont want to change the view and zoom in and out of the map that I produce.

I would like to use [this](https://gisgba.geologie.ac.at/arcgis/services/image/AT_GBA_GK50/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities) WMS server as overlay to a Google Maps map or a OpenStreetMap (so I can adjust the transparency) with geom_point() of my datapoints.

Is there a way to do this, or can I only use WMS with the 'leaflet' package?

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your `rgdal` package is built with WMS support then you can read WMS data from R using that. But you have to build the XML file that handles the request. Some initial efforts at doing that appear here:

https://github.com/louhos/takomo/tree/master/GIS

but its a bit of a construction kit and the linked site is in Finnish which might not be good for you.

Alternatively if you can work out the exact WMS URL for the image you want back from the WMS, construct it and then use `download.file` or similar web tools to get it, then use it like any other image underlay on a `ggplot` (`geom_raster` or something).